# Touch screen and two monitors

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, display, touchscreen

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04.4.
I have two monitors (one touchscreen and one regular). I've used xrandr to set regular screen right of touch screen, so extended display. Now ubuntu thinks the entire extended desktop is touch. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a solution that works for me.
I documented it [here](http://kovica.blogspot.com/2014/06/touchscreen-with-multiple-monitors.html).